# How to simplify multiple conditions in Python

Tags: python, multiple-conditions

I wrote a script in python that parses some strings.

The problem is that I need to check if the string contains some parts.
The way I found is not smart enough.

Here is my code:

```
if ("CondA" not in message) or ("CondB" not in message) or ("CondC" not in message) or ...:
```

Is there a way to optimize this? I have 6 other checks for this condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a generator with `any()` or `all()`:

```
if any(c not in message for c in ('CondA', 'CondB', ...)):
    ...
```

In Python 3, you could also make use of `map()` being lazy:

```
if not all(map(message.__contains__, ('CondA', 'CondB', ...))):
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `any` function:

```
if any(c not in message for c in ("CondA", "CondB", "CondC")):
    ...
```

Comment: I could use a list in the cycle?
E.g.: for c in list